# redirect keeps going to root after rendering correct page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails 5 application on which I'm displaying a form to let users upload multiple images. I am trying to redirect to another page after the images are saved, but for some reason it is redirecting back to root instead.

I can see in the rails server log that it is correctly redirecting to the expected page but once it's done, it then goes to root.

The form

```rb
<%= simple_form_for ProductReviewPhoto.new, url: product_review_photos_path do |f| %>

  <div id="selectedFiles"></div>

  <label class="myLabel">
    <%= f.file_field 'files[]', id: 'files', name: 'files[]', multiple: true %>
    <span>Séléctionner vos images</span>
  </label>

  <%= f.hidden_field :product_review_id, value: @product_review.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", disabled: true, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The #create in controller

```rb
def create
  @product_review_id = params[:product_review].to_i
  @new_photos = []
  params[:files].each do |p|
    @new_photos << ProductReviewPhoto.new(product_review_id: @product_review_id, photo: p)
  end

  if @new_photos.all?(&:save)
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Erreur, veuillez charger votre image à nouveau.'
  end
end
```

Rails server log after successfully saving images

```
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 2204ms (ActiveRecord: 5.2ms)

Started GET "/dashboard" for ::1 at 2019-08-01 15:11:49 +0200
...

Completed 200 OK in 328ms (Views: 288.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2019-08-01 15:11:49 +0200
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
...
```

I don't understand why it keeps going to root... all my other redirects work fine.

Comment: It is important to notice that you have two redirects. the first to `GET "/dashboard"` after creating the review works fine. But then there is a second redirect from the `dashboard"`. That probably means that you need to check your dashboards controller why there the second redirect is triggered. There might be a `before_action`, authorization missing or something else. But the problem is not the in the code that you posted in your question. The problem is on the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. This second redirect always happens, no matter which path I redirect to. It even does so when I ```redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)```. Is the second redirect really a redirect? I can't see any other 302 redirect in the log, except for the first one that's meant to be.

Comment: what's going on with `PagesController` ?

Comment: Oh my... I actually just realized that I was handling the post of this form with JS XHR, and I had a ```xhr.onload``` function that was redirecting to root upon ```status === 200```. You pointed me in the right direction though by saying that the error was not in the code that I posted.